# SqlFileStream Write bug?

Tags: .net, sql-server, filestream

I've been writing and reading PDF's to a SQL Server 2008 FileStream for a few months now without any major problems (apart from tedious user permissions). Yesterday I had a user inform me that some of their PDF's were being corrupted after being written into the FileStream. So, I did some debugging and I found the problem, but it appears to be a bug with the SqlFileStream libraries that write the file to the FileStream.

Here is my code that writes to the FileStream:

```
// Byte array representing the FileStream
byte[] fsBytes = (byte[])obj;

SqlFileStream sqlFS = new SqlFileStream(path, fsBytes, FileAccess.Write);

byte[] b = new byte[4096];
int read;

stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

while ((read = stream.Read(b, 0, b.Length)) > 0) {
    sqlFS.Write(b, 0, read);
}

sqlFS.Close();
```

From my debugging, I determined that the last iteration reading from the stream has a read value equal to 1253, which means that the last stream read has data in the byte array from index 0 to 1252, **and this is correct**. Everything at and after 1253 is from the previous read.

So, my understanding is that **sqlFS.Write(b, 0, 1253)** will write everything from index 0 to 1252 of the byte array into the SqlFileStream. However, it is actually writing **everything** in the byte array to the SqlFileStream. I have verified this by pulling the PDF back out of the database, and even though I can't view it normally since its now corrupted, I can still open it in a text editor and view the garbal at the end of it that doesn't belong there (all of the data that was at position 1253 and after).

I am doing something wrong here, or does the SqlFileStream Write method have a bug like I think it does?

What is odd is that I've uploaded quite a few other PDF's and text files and images and I've never seen this problem. I have no idea why it is occurring with some PDF's and not others...

**EDIT:**
Here is the code for my read method. The bug may be here as well (thanks to Remus for pointing this out!).

```
SqlFileStream objSqlFileStream = new SqlFileStream(path, objContext, FileAccess.Read);
objSqlFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

b = new byte[4096];
int read;

while ((read = objSqlFileStream.Read(b, 0, b.Length)) > 0) {
   Response.BinaryWrite(b);
}

objSqlFileStream.Close();
```

**EDIT #2 (fixed code):**

```
SqlFileStream objSqlFileStream = new SqlFileStream(path, objContext, FileAccess.Read);
objSqlFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

b = new byte[4096];
int read;

while ((read = objSqlFileStream.Read(b, 0, b.Length)) > 0) {
    if (read < 4096) {
        byte[] b2 = new byte[read];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(b, 0, b2, 0, read);
        Response.BinaryWrite(b2);
    }
    else
        Response.BinaryWrite(b);
}

objSqlFileStream.Close();
```

Comment: How do you verify the content, could be that your read methodology has the problem? What is the value of `SELECT DATALENGTH(filestreamcolumn) FROM Table WHERE ...` for your 1252 size PDF?

Comment: @Remus - I think you're right. I can see where the bug may be occurring at when I read from the FileStream.

Comment: @Remus - If you want to supply an answer stating that the logic problem is with my read then I'll be happy to mark it as the answer and give credit where its due. :)

Comment: `read < 4096` you shouldn't reuse a literal constant twice in code, think single definition, refactoring and such. better compare with `b.Length` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while ((read = objSqlFileStream.Read(b, 0, b.Length)) > 0) {
   Response.BinaryWrite(b);
}
```

This writes the entire original `byte[]` array `b` and ignores the size `read`. IS appaling that HttpResponse has no signature `.BinaryWrite(byte[], offset, size)`... I'm afraid you'll have to [`b.Resize(read);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx) before you write it out.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help to clear out the byte array after the write?

Comment: Probably, but I'm really just looking for someone to tell me "Hey, dummy, you're doing this wrong!" or "Yep, it looks like a SqlFileStream bug." But in the end I'm likely going to implement something like what you said. :(